# DNS Works Locally But Not Globally

Tags: dns, bind

I tried to setup and run my own DNS on an Ubuntu server using Bind. Assuming my hostname is example.com and the static ip on the server is 100.100.100.100, I get the following if I `dig example.com` locally:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.4-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34962
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        38400   IN  A   100.100.100.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        38400   IN  NS  example.com.
example.com.        38400   IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
example.com.        38400   IN  NS  ns2.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.com.    38400   IN  A   100.100.100.100
ns2.example.com.    38400   IN  A   100.100.100.100

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 13 09:59:37 BST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 141
```

Also if I do write `host example.com` I get the following:

```
  host example.com example.com has address 100.100.100.100 
  example.com mail is handled by 10 webmail.example.com.
```

The `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` is as follows:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/example.com.hosts";
        notify yes;
        }
```

The `/etc/bind/named.conf` is:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

Obviously I did update the DNS records on the name domain name provider more than 72 hours ago. Also, both traceroute and ping works for external addresses, such as 8.8.8.8, and I can access the static IP through a browser, however not for example.com.

Any idea how I can make the DNS globally known?

Answer (score 1):

Am answer that better matches the question....

You need to define a zone that declares your name server as a master, so that it will offer the answers to other servers, so you need at least a line:
    type master;
within that zone.

Here's what I have in my server's /etc/bind/named.conf.local
(on 14:04LTS), except that my file actually has 'notify no;' in the last view, but I believe you will need 'notify yes;' to publish the data.

```
#
# Do any local configuration here
#
#
# Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
# organization

include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

acl masters {
    # 195.62.28.14  # ns1.tsohost.co.uk;
    # 194.142.155.4 # ns2.tsohost.co.uk;
    # 95.142.154.15 # ns3.tsohost.co.uk;
};

acl internals {
    127.0.0.0/8;    # IPv4 localhost/loopback
    10.0.0.0/24;    # IPv4 localnel
    #::1/128;   # IPv6 localhost/loopback
    #fe80::/10; # IPv6 link-local
    # fec0::/10;    # IPv6 site-local ... deprecated
};

view "internal" {
    match-clients { internals; };
    recursion yes;
    zone "gscott.co.uk" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/internals/db.gscott.co.uk";
    };
};

view "external" {
    match-clients { any; };
    # recursion no;
    notify yes;
    zone "gscott.co.uk" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/externals/db.gscott.co.uk";
    };
};
```

Then you'll need the zone files themselves, e.g. something like:

```
;
;       gscott.co.uk
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     gscott.co.uk gscott.gscott.co.uk (
                        201411282233    ;       serial
                                604800  ;       refresh
                                86400   ;       Retry
                                2419200 ;       Expire
                                604800) ;       Negative cache TTL
;
@               IN      NS      ns1
                IN      MX  10  mail

barbican        IN      A       87.127.155.63   ; the outside world .. 'yer be dragons!
```

IMHO, unless you really *want* to do this, the quick solution is *much* simpler and less fraught.

Comment: Thanks, the problem still presist. I also updated the question. By the way where do you update the zone files? I think this is where I have a problem with.